# ruby test error Don't know how to build task 'db:test'

Tags: ruby, testing

I run rake db:test:prepare and I get the following error:
    Don't know how to build task 'db:test'
The development DB is populated

what could be causing the test db not to populate the data? The table structure gets created but there is no data in the tables

Comment: Can you give more details? E.g. if you use rails.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's `rake db:test:prepare` use a `:` to separate words rather then a space.

Comment: I use an ide so don't have to type anything. Sorry my typo

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened but after disconnecting and reconnecting the test DB which still didn't work I closed the IDE (Rubymine) and reopened it and then was able to successfully run rake db:test:prepare